# In NavigtationController Embedded ViewController is not instantiated from Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I have a storyboard with a ViewController, embedded into NavigatonController (so the Storyboard shows one box with an arrow to another).

If I create my ViewController,

```
[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController:@"viewControllerID"]
```

it works, but the View is not within the NavController

If I create the Nav Controller from StoryBoard:

```
[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController:@"NavControllerID"]
```

I get an empty Navigationcontroller, without View.

How to achieve both?

Comment: Show a screen shot of the storyboard (section), include the id of each controller. `instantiateInitialViewController:` isn't an existing method so show the real code you're using.

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102978/swrevealviewcontroller-without-using-navigationcontroller/23105142#23105142 for navigate the particular view controller

Comment: You need to set the rootViewController for the UINavigationController.

Comment: Sorry, not allowed to post pictures here yet. Will show the sources soon.

Comment: @ArnieSchwarzvogel upload them to imgur or something like that and post the links here

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the `UIViewCotroller` is embed as `rootViewController` to the `UINavigationController` .

```
 UIViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerID"];

 UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: viewController]; // [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController:@"NavControllerID"];
```

Use the `navigationController` object to proceed

Comment: But this will create the empty UINavigationController, not the one I set up in Storyboard