# Ios-Segue to a UIViewController not happening after using pushViewController to load TableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am currently working on an `IOS` app to browse the folders on a remote computer and display the  pictures. Now in order to browse the folders I am using the same `table view` and updating its `cells`, each time the user presses on a tile. Now after getting to the final list of contents(Images), I am trying to use a segue to navigate to `UIViewController` to display the `Images`. But I am getting an error: *"segue not found"*.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath {
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
// Fetch device
self->browseObjID = [avObjArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if([self->browseObjID isFolder])//To load same table view for browsing the folders
{
  ContentL1TableViewController *targetViewController = [[[ContentL1TableViewController alloc] initWithMediaDevice:_devSelected andObjectId:self->browseObjID ];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:targetViewController animated:YES];
}
else
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DisplayImage" sender:self];// display final image
}
```

Comment: First, don't use `->` syntax. Second, check the name of the segue in Interface Builder.

Comment: Probably, either you don't have a segue with that name (spelling?), or the controller you have this code in is not the same instance you connected the segue to in the storyboard.

Comment: first ur DisplayImage identifier does not match, other wise if u used the storyborad need to identify the storyboard

Comment: if u use the storyboard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102978/swrevealviewcontroller-without-using-navigationcontroller/23105142#23105142

Comment: Please see my answer. Your view controller is not created from a storyboard (`alloc] initWithMediaDevice...`). Therefore you cannot called perform segue as there are no segues (because there is no storyboard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only segue from a view controller that is created by a storyboard.

I'm assuming that you defined this TVC in a storyboard initially but that is only the first one.

When you are going to the subsequent TVCs you are creating these using alloc init and so they don't have a storyboard with a segue defined.

You should either create your image view controller using a xib file and load it from the xib or create it in code. Both would be easier.

Or you could define a "circular" segue that goes from the TVC back to itself and use this instead of creating one using alloc init all the time.