# How can to go back to previous view programmatically without UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

How can to go back to previous view programmatically without `UINavigationController`, because all examples that I have found use `UINavigationController` ?

I am making view for sending feedback and I would like to use this view in many more apps.
If I use UINavigationController than app need to have `UINavigationController` to use my view for sending feedback.

Is this possible to do and how ?

This is code how I show my view for sending feedback:

```
- (IBAction)showFeedbackView:(id)sender {

    WOC_FeedbackViewController *feedbackView = [[WOC_FeedbackViewController alloc] init];

    [self presentViewController:feedbackView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102978/swrevealviewcontroller-without-using-navigationcontroller/23105142#23105142

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this to go back

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your project works (Storyboards or XIB) you can use presentViewController. But thats when you keep a reference on your last viewController's identifier.

If you know the ID of your viewController NSString *yourID;

1) Init your viewController

For storyboard

```
UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:yourID];
```

For XIB

```
UIViewController *vc = [UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:yourID bundle:nil];
```

2) Presenting your ViewController

```
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

P.S This is a way to do this, but you should use `navigationController` because you can keep memory of a `viewController` on stack so when you need to access it again, you can access it faster. In other words, `UINavigationController` is applied in every iOS Application you see on App Store.

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift**, you can use following line of code to go back to previous view controller **without navigation controller**:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```