# Navigate to a specific view controller in the story board

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I have an ios App, with a single story board with over 20 screens, and i need to add more

is there some option/shortcut that will allow me to display the screen i want to work on, just by typing the name of the class that it implements?

it bothers me that every time i want to edit/change the ui, i need to open the story board file and start searching for the little square denoted by my view controller class, to edit it

Comment: use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102978/swrevealviewcontroller-without-using-navigationcontroller/23105142#23105142

Comment: i am not talking about the code, i am talking about the interface of xcode, so that when i display the storyboard file, instead of scrolling and searching for the screen i want to edit, i click some key code and enter the name of the screen i want to edit, and it becomes centered on my **computer** screen (not my ios device), no ios coding involved whatsoever

Comment: You can rename your view controllers in Storyboard's Document Outline pane as you wish. So it is easy to find them if you give them a name that suits you.

Comment: I did that, but i have over 20 viewcontroller in the storyboard, and it takes me forever to find them

Comment: You can use the search field at the bottom of the Document Outline.

Comment: i never noticed that, thank you