# Could not find a navigation controller after manually launching Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a viewcontroller that features a form, once this has been submitted I need the app to move back to the 'home' page this is done with:

```
ITViewController *svc =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"home"];
[svc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
[self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

However once I have done this and try to click on any of the buttons on the 'home' page I end up with the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
> reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue. Push segues can only be used when the source
> controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

My storyboard looks like:

[image]

Email View controller is where we go back from from

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102978/swrevealviewcontroller-without-using-navigationcontroller/23105142#23105142

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
ITViewController *svc =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"home"];
UINavigationController *navcon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:svc];
[navcon setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
[self presentViewController:navcon animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Your problem is that you are presenting a ITViewController out of a navigation controller. Then you try to perform a segue. Since there is no navigation controller, your app crashes. Embed your ITViewController into a `UINavigationController` and it will work.

**Edit:**

By the way, if you just want to go back to the home view controller, I suggest instead of allocating a new view controller and present it modally, just make your navigation controller pop to its root view controller. Instead of:

```
ITViewController *svc =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"home"];
[svc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
[self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Do:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```