# error in Xcode 5:could not find storyboardname?

Tags: ios, xcode

i created custom button using objective-c.when i click this button, next view will  have to push.To do this i have written code as shown in below:

```
-(void)click1:(UIButton *)sender{
NSString * storyboardName = @"mystoryboard";
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName  bundle:nil];
secondViewController *add = [[secondViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"secondView" bundle:nil];
add =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"newseg1"];
[self presentViewController:add animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I got error like this:"could not find storyboardName in NSBundle...".i don't know what i have to put in storyboardName.can anyone explain it?

Comment: If your method is in a `UIViewController` and the target view controller is in the same storyboard, you can use `[self storyboard]` to get the current storyboard rather than using `[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName...]`.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102978/swrevealviewcontroller-without-using-navigationcontroller/23105142#23105142

Answer (score 0):

Your `storyboardName` should be storyBoard file name in your project.It is case sensitive.If in project explorer you are seeing `Main.storyboard` just pass `Main` without `storyboard`

```
NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
```

Comment: thanks.i created a secondViewcontroller in storyboard and created push with identifier as newseg1.but the error show as:"Receiver (<ViewController: 0x8b36ac0>) has no segue with identifier 'newseg1''"   will u pls help me?