# Error:does't contain a view controller with identifier?

Tags: ios, xcode5

```
-(void)btnclick1:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString *storyboardName=@"Main";

    UIStoryboard* storyboard1 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName
                                                         bundle:nil];


    secondViewController *add = [[secondViewController alloc]init];
 add =[storyboard1 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nextseg"];
    [self.view addSubview:add.view];

    [self presentViewController:add
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];



}
```

I got error:  reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'nextseg''

Comment: Do you give identifier to view controller in storyboard? In other words What is "nextseg" from where u get this?

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102978/swrevealviewcontroller-without-using-navigationcontroller/23105142#23105142

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Storyboard ID` for the xib you want to use in the MainStoryboard Settings for the XIB, see image. In your case it should be `@"nextseg"`

[image]

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Just add [NSBundle mainBundle] to the bundle argument where you get the storyboard from. Hope this helps

```
-(void)btnclick1:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString *storyboardName=@"Main";

    UIStoryboard* storyboard1 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName
                                                     bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];


    secondViewController *add = [[secondViewController alloc]init];
    add =[storyboard1 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nextseg"];
    [self.view addSubview:add.view];

    [self presentViewController:add
                   animated:YES
                 completion:nil];



}
```

Also make sure you have a identifier "nextseg" for your view controller. "nextseg" should not be the identifier of the segue leading to the view controller, but it should be for the view controller